# Execute code before start of method

Tags: .net, selenium, automation

I have a set of code that i execute in all my test methods, like the login code. Is it possible to minimize that lines of code and ensure it is run before the test method runs, like attributing the method. if we take it as some attribute, then it should also take parameters, wondering how is this achievable. Plmk.

Comment: The code looks like this:
using(Browser.Initialize(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name,"en-us"))
{
//code that is repeated about 5 lines
//Code that varies based on method, about 10 lines
Browser.Close();
}

Answer (score 1):

In all the unit test frameworks, there is a feature to execute common code before and after tests. Below shows an example of NUnit:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestFixtureLifetime
{
    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeTest()
    { Console.WriteLine("BeforeTest"); }

    [TearDown]
    public void AfterTest()
    { Console.WriteLine("AfterTest"); }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    { Console.WriteLine("Test1"); }

    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    { Console.WriteLine("Test2"); }
}
```

When this class is ran, we get the following output: .

```
BeforeTest
Test1
AfterTest
BeforeTest
Test2
AfterTest
```

Also,`[Setup]` and  `[Teardown]` methods are optional. We can mix and match their presence based on requirement.

Comment: Thanks for this example. I am using Selenium, and couldn't find TextFixture class in there.

Comment: TestFixture is NUnit attribute. Aren't you using any test framemork to drive  selenium tests?